# Symfony2 and Doctrine - Adding a property doesn't inherit parent associative properties in custom bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, akeneo

I am trying to add a property in an entity in a third party bundle. Here is my yml file

```
Acme\Bundle\AppBundle\Entity\Group:
type: entity
table: pim_catalog_group_new
changeTrackingPolicy: DEFERRED_EXPLICIT 
fields:
    sortOrder:
        type: integer        
manyToOne:
    family:
        targetEntity: Pim\Component\Catalog\Model\FamilyInterface
        joinColumn:
            name: family_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: 'SET NULL'
```

When i run the following command

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

It gives me `id, family_id, sortOrder, code` and other simple fields but associative fields from parent class are not included. Here is the produced migration script (Notice that oneToMany, manyToMany associative fields from parent are missing):

```
    public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE pim_catalog_group (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, family_id INT DEFAULT NULL, code VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, sortOrder INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_3196D4CB77153098 (code), INDEX IDX_3196D4CBC35E566A (family_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pim_catalog_group ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3196D4CBC35E566A FOREIGN KEY (family_id) REFERENCES pim_catalog_family (id) ON DELETE SET NULL');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pim_catalog_group_translation DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_622D98DB7E366551');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pim_catalog_group_translation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_622D98DB7E366551 FOREIGN KEY (foreign_key) REFERENCES pim_catalog_group (id) ON DELETE CASCADE');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pim_catalog_association_group DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_E91414DDFE54D947');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pim_catalog_association_group ADD CONSTRAINT FK_E91414DDFE54D947 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES pim_catalog_group (id) ON DELETE CASCADE');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pim_catalog_group_product DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_7AC0C83AFE54D947');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE pim_catalog_group_product ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7AC0C83AFE54D947 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES pim_catalog_group (id) ON DELETE CASCADE');
}
```

Comment: PHP inheritance will not work in Doctrine as long as they aren't mapped using superclass or related. Especially once configuration formats (yml, annotation, xml) are mixed this will be tough, so easiest is to override the whole entity. Also see: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

As per @Rvanlaak suggestion:

> PHP inheritance will not work in Doctrine as long as they aren't mapped using superclass or related. Especially once configuration formats (yml, annotation, xml) are mixed this will be tough, so easiest is to override the whole entity. Also see: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

I ended up solving this problem by copying whole orm file into my custom bundle and modifying it to add my custom fields and associations.

Comment: Hi, right buy Akeneo has a system that allow you to do it without copying the whole file. You even continue to use the default table if you wish. Check their documentation to do it for products here : https://docs.akeneo.com/latest/cookbook/catalog_structure/overriding_the_orm_product_value.html It should be quite the same for the grouping.